# The "Many Worlds" description of quantum mechamics and the "Multiverse"

Tags: cosmology, universe, quantum-interpretations, multiverse, anthropic-principle

I see a Phys.SE [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10140/2451), asking if the "Many Worlds" and the "Multiverse" ideas are essentially equivalent. This question was quickly squashed with a no answer. I would like to rephrase the question.

Could the "Many Worlds" interpretation of quantum mechanics be an alternate explanation of our "fine tuned" universe?

What if what we see as the beginning of the universe is just when our universe with its physical laws and fundamental dimensionless constants "branched off"?

I am not looking for opinions here, but rather reasons to discredit this idea.

Comment: Sean Carroll, a respected physicist, writes about this possibility [here](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2011/05/26/are-many-worlds-and-the-multiverse-the-same-idea/).

Comment: The idea there is that physical constants, and even physical laws, might be aspects of the universe's quantum state and thus subject to the same quantum superposition (branching) as in Many Worlds -- just as @JackR.Woods proposes.  There seems to be nothing (yet) to discredit the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The Many Worlds interpretation (MWI) of quantum mechanics wasn't intended to be an explanation for the fact our universe is 'fine tuned' in a certain way, since it doesn't postulate the existence of multiple universes with different physical laws. Instead it assumes that the many worlds are super-positions of the possible states allowed under the rules of quantum mechanics - ie, the rules allowed in the universe as is.

Comment: I read the blog by Sean Carroll in the comment above and he thinks that the idea could be a possibility. The way I see it, imagining a near infinite amount of universes with ours being one of the few that allows our existence is just about as hard to swallow as near infinite branches of the wave function where we exist in one of those branches. Hard to swallow, but the only other explanation for our "fine tuned" universe seems to be "a creator".

Comment: @JackR.Woods Sean might have been talking about another multiverse idea, where each universe is different in terms of its key physical parameters, and ours happens to be one that's suited for our kind of life-form.